# Can't auto generate controller with views from EF

Tags: c#, postgresql, visual-studio, entity-framework, npgsql

Steps I did:

- Install Npgsql EF extension for Visual studio
- Create a new Project
- Install Npgsql from nuget
- Install EntityFramework6.Npgsql from nuget
- Create connection to postgresql using Server Explorer
- Create ADO.NET Entity Data Model - EF Designer From DB
- Compile
- Create Controller using Entity Framework

The last step give me this error:

```
There was an error running the selected code generator: 
'Unable to retrieve metadata for 'MyProject.Models.MyClass' 
 Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed.
```

[image]

So I can connect to postgres, create the model from DB, but cant auto generate view from EF.

Further technical details

- Npgsql version: 3.2.7
- EntityFramework6.Npgsql 3.1.1
- PostgreSQL version: 9.4
- Operating system: Windows 10
- Visual Studio Community 2017 v15.4

In the webconfig I have this section

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Npgsql" publicKeyToken="5d8b90d52f46fda7" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.2.7.0" newVersion="3.2.7.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Not sure if need add anything else so VS see it as Installed.

Comment: could you update the title of this question as its very miss leading/confusing in relation to your issue.

Comment: @Seabizkit What you suggest? For me tell what is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this in config file:

```
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Npgsql"/>
      <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" description=".Net Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7" support="FF"/>
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Now have to check why that line wasn't add it on the setup :/